# Params' register or stack in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c

I am confusing about one question.See an example:

```
-(void)DIYLog:(NSString *)format, ...
{
   NSLog(...);
}
```

It's just an example for fun. We all know that we can't pass "..." as parameters for NSLog. So I'm Curious about passing one "variable parameters" to another.
I already know that params are passed by register or stack, But, The key point is , how can I implement it in Objective-C or C.

---

I think I make you misunderstand. NSLog is just an example to be explained. Let me make another.
It's about passing params to **id objc_msgSend(id self, SEL op, ...)**.

```
-(void)DIY_msgSend:(id)target selector:(SEL)op params:(id)param, ...
{
    objc_msgSend(target, op, ...);
}
```

So, the key is, how I can pass those variable parameters to another function which also need variable parameters.

Comment: I dont understand your question at all, can you be more explicit and write more examples?

Comment: I think the question is "How can I write a method that takes variable parameters pass those parameters to another function like NSLog."

Comment: Whether parameters are passed on the stack or in registers is entirely an implementation detail of the targeted architecture and the parameters being passed....

Comment: This is not the thing I need. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C `va_list` type can be created from variadic arguments and passed to functions/methods that accept a `va_list` parameter. Eg:

```
- (void)logFormat:(NSString *)format, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSLogv(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

However, there is no portable way of passing a `va_list` to a standard variadic function as you want to do.